# How to convert selected text into single paragraph in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using Libreoffice in Ubuntu 14.04 with unity.

What I have is a libreoffice writer file which looks like, say

```
The
quick

brown fox

jumps
over the lazy

dog
```

I would like to convert it into single paragraph, so that it looks like

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

How would I do this, with minimum efforts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`Regular Expressions`** search enabled, **search for `$` and replace with a space**. You may do another search/replace to reduce multiple spaces to one space.

Alternatively, you may first remove all empty paragraphs using a regex search for `^$`, replacing it with "nothing" (empty string), and afterwards replace the paragraph marks by spaces as described.

[image]

Take care that this search/replace may affect the entire document - if you want to preserve some paragraph marks, you should first select the text to edit and restrict the search/replace to "current selection only" (option just above the regex option).

See also the [OpenOffice documentation on search/replace using regular expressions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Tabs.2C_newlines.2C_paragraphs_.5Ct_.5Cn_.24) - those explanations and advices often apply to LibreOffice, too.